# Run project specific _vimrc in windows?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

I'm attempted to duplicate [this functionality](https://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/project-specific-vimrc/) in a windows environment running gvim 8.1 but it doesn't appear to pick up my changes.

I've updated my `$VIMRC\_vimrc` with

```
set exrc
set secure
```

and my local _vimrc contains

```
set fileencoding=latin1
```

And when I try to load a file with the project-local _vimrc file it doesn't work because when I check `:set fileencoding` it's set to `fileencoding=`

Comment: Just to debug the obvious: Have you checked the output of `:scriptname` to be sure that your local vimrc isn't used? Also maybe you could put `echom 'Hello'` in your local vimrc and check `:message`. This way you would be sure that the problem comes from your vimrc not being sourced and not something preventing the encoding to be set properly.

Comment: Note: `exrc` isn't actually _project specific_ as it only works with files in the exact same directory (not in subdirectories) -- this may be a reason for the problem you're observing if your files are in spread in subfolders. Several plugins offer this feature. At least I use [mine](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc/) on Windows as well.